# Codeigniter router setup

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, router

**My website is running on Codeigniter.
I need a help to tweak the URI using the *router.php***

Currently I have a URL like this -

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/use_advanced/true/from_tmstmp_deal_duration/1363581836/to_tmstmp_deal_duration/1371357836/
```

I want to mask it as -

```
http://www.mysite.com/deals/
```

that is, when user hits this url, it will work as the above long url but in the browser address bar, it will still show http://www.mysite.com/deals/

**NOTE**: in the long url, 1363581836 is current unix-timestamp, 1371357836 is 90days future unix-timestamp.

in routes.php -

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
$route['deals'] =
"search/use_advanced/true/from_tmstmp_deal_duration/$1/to_tmstmp_deal_duration/$2/";
```

in frontend.module.php -

```
$route['deals/(.*)'] = array('title' => 'Deals','action' => 'search',);
```

Comment: Just create the route, and add some `time()` logic stuff for the dates. What's the issue here? Have you *tried* it?

Comment: no, not working.
I have updated my route file. It is still showing the old long url.

I have added this -
`$route['deals'] =
"search/use_advanced/true/from_tmstmp_deal_duration/$1/to_tmstmp_deal_duration/$2/";`

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have added the code blocks.

Comment: When using `$#` within the route, you must setup the groups to capture the variables you want to pass, i.e. `$route['deals/(:num)/(:num)' = 'search/use_advanced/true/from_tmstmp_deal_duration/$1/to_tmstmp_deal_duration/$2/';` which will convert `/deals/100/200` to `search/use_advanced/true/from_tmstmp_deal_duration/100/to_tmstmp_deal_duration/200/` etc.

Comment: Do you have a controller called `deals`? The way your route is set up, it will look for that.

Comment: i rly suggest you using 3 max 4 uri segments in any cases, for your urls, just my 2cents

Answer (score 2):

why not this in **routes.php**:

```
$route['deals/(:any)'] = "search/use_advanced/$1";
```